# How to apply Gradient descent to the equation ax²+bx+c?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I want to apply gradient descent to the equation ax²+bx+c to see whether it gives a better accuracy on a sample dataset.
I have used the code

```
cost = (1/2) * (sum(((y - y_current)**2)))
a_gradient = -sum(mul(X,X)*(y - y_current))
b_gradient = -sum(X * (y - y_current))
c_gradient = -sum(y - y_current)
```

where y current is the Y predicted.
I think the problem is in the differential of the unknown variable (a,b,c) as on using this code I encounter this error.

```
<ipython-input-73-3e57c8f474a1>:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  a_current = a_current - (learning_rate * a_gradient)
```

and the value of cost function tends to infinity.

cost function vs number of iteration graph:

[image: cost function vs number of iteration graph]

please tell me the correct differentiation or any other solution you can think of
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of

**ax<sup>2</sup>+bx + c**

is

**2*a*x+b**

in order to apply **gradient descent** you need to subtract the derivative     **2*a*x+b**  multiplied by the **learning rate** from the calculated new value at each step

**Y<sub>previous</sub> = Y<sub>predicted</sub>**

**Y<sub>predicted</sub> = Y<sub>predicted</sub> - l<sub>r</sub>(2aY<sub>previous</sub>+b)**

where **lr** is the learning rate and Y<sub>previous</sub> the initial value.

For example for the function **3x<sup>2</sup>+4x+1** the roots are **-1** and **-1/3**, and the derivative is  **6x + 4.** . Setting the starting point to **3.0**

```
y0=3.0
lr=0.01
y=lr*(6*y0+4)
while abs(y-y0)>0.00000001:
    y0=y
    y=y-lr*(6*y0+4)
print(y)

-0.6666666622832803
```

is a minimum.

[image]